# android Linkify first occurrence only

Tags: android, linkify

i am using Linkify with a custom TransformFilter.  Is it possible to tell linkify to only match the first occurence of my pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a MatchFilter for that, like this

```
   MatchFilter matcher = new MatchFilter() {
        boolean firstTime;
        @Override
        public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
            if(firstTime) {
                return true;
                firstTime = false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Hope it helps